# Layout of bar charts in Latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot, bar-chart

I created a bar chart, but it does not look good:

[image]

Problems:

1. the values above the bars does not look good. I want to have it on top of the bars and with slightly smaller font size;
2. The lay-out looks very cramped. I want to control the font size of the bar charts if possible;
3. I want to have a larger spacing between each groups, i.e., more spacing between 1 and 2, 2 and 3 etc;
4. I want to have the legend (Measured & Model) on top of each other, rather than side by side;
5. Group 9 does not appear on the bar chart, but I have it in my code;
6. I do not want spacing between the bars (i.e. no spacing between blue and red).

This is what I used:

```
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
        \begin{adjustbox}{width=\textwidth, height= 75mm}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
        x tick label style={
        /pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
        ylabel=$H_{m0}$,
        xlabel= {Position},
        enlargelimits=0.05,
        legend style={at={(0,1)},
          anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
            nodes near coords,
            every node near coord/.append style={font=\tiny},
           nodes near coords align={vertical},
           ybar interval=0.8,
        ]
\addplot [gray!20!gray,fill=gray!80!gray]
    coordinates {(01,0.150) (02,0.166)
         (03,0.174) (04,0.186) (05,0.187) (06,0.152) (07,0.218) (08,0.187) (09,0.156)};
\addplot  [black!20!black,fill=black!80!black]
    coordinates {(01,0.153) (02,0.162) 
         (03,0.178) (04,0.177) (05,0.222) (06,0.233) (07,0.323) (08,0.301) (09,0.233)};
        \legend{Measured, Model}
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{adjustbox}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ybar=0pt` instead `ybar interval`. Adjust the width of the bars to your needs. Set `width` and `height` for the `axis` environment. Remove `legend columns=-1`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        width=\textwidth,height=75mm,% <- added
        x tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=},
        ylabel=$H_{m0}$,
        xlabel= {Position},
        %enlargelimits=0.05,% <- commented, default is .1
        legend style={
          at={(0,1)},
          anchor=north west,% <- changed
          %legend columns=-1% <- commented
        },
        nodes near coords,
        every node near coord/.append style={font=\tiny},
        %nodes near coords align={vertical},% <- commented, default
        ybar=0pt,%<- changed
        bar width=13pt% <- added
      ]
      \addplot
        coordinates {(01,0.150) (02,0.166)
          (03,0.174) (04,0.186) (05,0.187) (06,0.152) (07,0.218) (08,0.187) (09,0.156)};
      \addplot
        coordinates {(01,0.153) (02,0.162) 
          (03,0.178) (04,0.177) (05,0.222) (06,0.233) (07,0.323) (08,0.301) (09,0.233)};
      \legend{Measured, Model}
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```